# shadow jar incomplete: org.springframework.boot.loader.wrapper.ThinJarWrapper not included

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I am working on a very minimal RestController spring-boot project. I am producing two jar files: 1/ using the Thin-Launcher of spring, and 2/ a shadow jar for AWS Lambda.

The thin jar is tiny with 16k, while the shadow jar is large with 22M. Both is expected.

When I run the tiny jar "java -jar tiny.jar" the server starts up and works. When I start the shadow jar, I get

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.springframework.boot.loader.wrapper.ThinJarWrapper
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.loader.wrapper.ThinJarWrapper
```

and indeed, the boot loader ThinJarWrapper was not packed into the shadow jar.

I can't figure out how to get it running. Here is my build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.4'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.3'
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '8.1.1'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'org.springframework.boot.experimental.thin-launcher' version "1.0.31.RELEASE"
}

group = 'wirklich.xyz'
version = '1.0.0'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "2023.0.0-M1")
}

assemble.dependsOn = [thinJar, shadowJar]

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
            versionMapping {
                usage('java-api') {
                    fromResolutionOf('runtimeClasspath')
                }
                usage('java-runtime') {
                    fromResolutionResult()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

shadowJar.mustRunAfter thinJar

import com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.transformers.*

shadowJar {
    archiveClassifier = 'aws'
    manifest {
        inheritFrom(project.tasks.thinJar.manifest)
    }
    // Required for Spring
    mergeServiceFiles()
    append 'META-INF/spring.handlers'
    append 'META-INF/spring.schemas'
    append 'META-INF/spring.tooling'
    append 'META-INF/spring/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports'
    append 'META-INF/spring/org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.ManagementContextConfiguration.imports'
    transform(PropertiesFileTransformer) {
        paths = ['META-INF/spring.factories']
        mergeStrategy = "append"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-function-adapter-aws'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-function-context'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws.serverless:aws-serverless-java-container-springboot3:2.0.0-M2'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually had the same problem.

Using "gradlew assemble" instead of "gradlew shadowJar" created the correct MANIFEST inside of the shadowJar.